# How to combine two list which are in a single list in Tcl?

Tags: concatenation, tcl

```
set a {1 3}
set b {}
set c_num {2 10 15 30}
lappend a $c_num
set d [concat $a $b]
puts $d
```

I want to combine this a and b set but the values should be separated.
from above code I get output as 1 3 {2 10 15 30}
instead I want output as 1 3 2 10 15 30

if there any solution please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change `$d`'s value from `1 3 {2 10 15 30}` to `1 3 2 10 15 30`, there are a few ways.

One seemingly simple way is using `join`

```
join $d
  --> 1 3 2 10 15 30
```

...but this `join` is actually a string command.   To illustrate further, add a second argument to `join` and see how often the joining character appears.

```
join $d "#"
  --> 1#3#2 10 15 30
```

Because Tcl doesn't have strict typing, a string can often be used as an argument to a list command (like `lindex` or `llength`).  It's always more memory efficient to avoid converting values from strings to lists.

The `concat` command is a list command to form a new list from its arguments.   Using the `{*}` operator converts the elements of a list into individual arguments.

```
concat {*}$d
   --> 1 3 2 10 15 30
```

The best solution would be to avoid needing to use `join` or `concat` at all.  Append multiple arguments to your list with the `{*}` operator instead of appending a list to a list.

Comment: I found that using `join $var` is actually 20% faster than `concat {*}$var` for large lists.   There's probably a penalty for calling `concat` with so many arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of lists and you want to make a list of base elements? Try `concat {*}$a`. In this case, you can combine that with concatenating the list in `$b`; nested calls to `concat` can be simplified.

Comment: or, `lappend a {*}$c_num` ?